# Vincular autenticación biométrica con usuario en firebase

Tags: flutter, autenticación, firebase-auth

tengo una duda, ya que quiero poder ingresar a una app que estoy diseñando con la opción de datos biométricos (para ser una alternativa al correo y contraseña). He visto el paquete local_auth, pero si yo quiero vincular esos datos con un usuario de firebase ¿Qué debo hacer? Es decir para obtener la información, etc. Y que pueda hacer login solo con los datos biométricos y poder recibir la información del usuario de firebase. De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) y cuando el usuario inicie sesión guardas las credenciales con `shared_preferences`.

Supongamos que las credenciales son `dni` y `celular` tu guardarías en `shared_preferences` de la siguiente manera:

```
     //SAVE DNI 
       Future<void> saveUserIdentification(String dni) async {
        final pfrc = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
        await pfrc.setString("dni", dni);
      }

      //GET DNI
      Future<String> getUserIdentification() async {
        final pfrc = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

        return pfrc.getString("dni") ?? "";
  }
```

Sería uno similar para el `celular` en caso que esas sean las credenciales.

Y ya una vez que quiera autenticarse biometricamente creas una función donde obtengas los datos ya guardados en `shared_preferences` y luego haces la consulta a la base de datos.

Esta es la forma más sencilla y rápida que creo que te ayudará.

Comment: comprendo, muchas gracias por la respuesta, voy a implementarlo.

Comment: si van a guardar datos sensible en shared preferences, recomiendo mejor usar el package flutter_secure_storage